# Can't install LibreOffice 5 on Linux Mint 17.2, policy rule not taken into account?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, libreoffice, ppa

I'm trying to install the package by following *web upd8* article [Install LibreOffice 5.0 In Ubuntu Or Linux Mint Via PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/install-libreoffice-50-in-ubuntu-or.html), with the **difference I use the Fresh PPA**.

#### Environment

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Release:        17.2
Codename:       rafaela
```

#### Pinnig rule

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/libreoffice-ppa.pref
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-libreoffice-ppa
Pin-Priority: 701
```

#### Installation

I then add the ppa and update/dist-upgrade

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

#### Cache Policy

Yet the cache policy still has an incorrect priority for the package.

```
$ apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:4.4.3~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1
  Version table:
     1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1:4.4.3~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1 0
        700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ rafaela/import amd64 Packages
     1:4.2.8-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:4.2.3~rc3-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirrors.coreix.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

#### Question

Why is my rule not taken into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

Wrong origin in the pinning rule of `/etc/apt/preferences.d/libreoffice-ppa.pref`:

```
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-libreoffice-ppa
```

**should be** (remove `-ppa`):

```
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-libreoffice
```

#### Long answer

You want to download the package from

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main
```

So if you look at

[`http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release`](http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release)

you will find

> ```
> Origin: LP-PPA-libreoffice
> Label: LibreOffice Fresh
> Suite: trusty
> Version: 14.04
> Codename: trusty
> Date: Sat, 10 Oct 2015  7:06:48 UTC
> Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
> Components: main
> Description: Ubuntu Trusty 14.04
> MD5Sum:
> ...
> ```

So you should change `/etc/apt/preferences.d/libreoffice-ppa.pref` accordingly.

Comment: I can't reach the realease link, can you check it?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I'm talking about: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release being disconnected